# Sinon stub - mocking a function which returns an array of objects

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, sinon

I am trying to stub the following code

```
async function logUpdate(client) {
  const results = await client.query(query.toParam());
  const { count, timestamp } = results.rows[0];

  await db.updateDatasourceLogs(destdb, DB.src, TABLES.src, timestamp, count);
}
```

This is the following code i am using to stub the above code

```
  fakeClient = {
      query: sinon.stub().resolves(fakeRows),
    };

   const rowData = {
      count: 1,
      timestamp: ''
   };

    fakeRows = {
      rows: sinon.stub().returns([rowData]),
    };

   fakeSequel = {
       useFlavour: sinon.stub().returns(toParam: () => false,),
   };
```

I am getting an error for destructuring

**TypeError: Cannot destructure property `count` of 'undefined' or 'null'.**

at line

```
const { count, timestamp } = results.rows[0];
```

**how to stub the above line?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we look at the body of your `logUpdate` function, we see it begins with the following two lines:

```
const results = await client.query(query.toParam());
const { count, timestamp } = results.rows[0];
```

This code says:

1. Await the Promise returned by the call to `client.query` and assign
   it to a variable called `results`.
2. `results` is an Object with a property called `rows` which is an
   Array whose 0th element should be an Object with `count` and
   `timestamp` properties - which we destructure into local variables.

This implies that the value of results looks like:

```
{
  "rows": [
    {
      "count": 1
      "timestamp": "0"
    }
  ]
}
```

However, in our stubbing code, we have the following:

```
fakeRows = {
  rows: sinon.stub().returns([rowData]),
};
```

Which says that `fakeRows` is an Object with a `rows` property whose value *is a function* that *returns* `[rowData]`.

If we were to implement this Object without sinon, it would look like:

```
{
  "rows": function () {
    return [
      {
        "count": 1
        "timestamp": "0"
      }
    ];
  }
}
```

Notice the difference between the structure that `logUpdate` is expecting and what `fakeRows` actually provides. Specifically, `logUpdate` expects `results` to have a `rows` *Array*, but, with our stubbed code, it has a `rows` *Function*!

We can fix this simply by having `fakeRows` reference our `rowData` directly:

```
const fakeRows = {
  rows: [rowData]
};
```